# Align buttons bars of separate areas at the right bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to align two button bars of independent HTML areas (marked as red and green, splitter between them) at the right bottom of its areas on the same height. Also the button bar should be fixed at the pages buttom, also if the content of an area is smaller or heigher.

Desired result:
[image: desired result]

I was not able to got them to the right side. Thats my current result:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * { font-size:30px }
            html,body { height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <nav>
            Logo, Navigation, Top Bar etc.
        </nav>
        
        <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;background:silver;position:absolute;top:65px;bottom:20px;right:20px;left:260px;">
            
            <div style="flex-basis:30%;order:0;border:5px solid red">
                <div style="padding-bottom:60px;background:pink">
                    Content area 1<br/><br/>
                    Content area 1
                </div>

                <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;background:pink;">
                    <div style="margin:10px 0;">
                        <button>Area 1.1</button>
                        <button>Area 1.2</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div style="flex-basis:auto;flex-grow:1;flex-shrink:1;order:2;border:5px solid green">
                
                <div style="padding-bottom:60px;background:lightgreen">
                    Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2
                </div>

                <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;background:lightgreen;">
                    <div style="margin:10px 0;">
                        <button>Area 2.1</button>
                        <button>Area 2.2</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div style="flex-basis:auto;order:1;;background:gray">S<br/>P<br/>L<br/>I<br/>T<br/>T<br/>E<br/>R</div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to solve this better? I thought about flexbox, but don't know how to get both button bars the same height.

Comment: Your code needs to get changed completely, because using `position: absolute` into everything, is not ideal! I'll give you a hand on this, give me a moment.

Comment: Just a side note: I strongly recommend using an external stylesheet, or at least internal, but avoid using inline CSS when you can. You can read more about this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-css-cascading-style-sheet/). Also learn about [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Id_selectors)'s, and your CSS will get a lot less complicated.

Comment: @Thomas I forgot to say that on my answer, it really is better. Everything is organized and easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations! I usally use CSS but for fast testing some styles I definie them sometimes directly in HTML element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using any `position`, you can achieve the layout you wanted, way easier and better looking! 
Also, use a `CSS` file, it's more practical and helpful! Have everything organized and you'll see how great it is!

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tables {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 410px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh - 75px);
}

.pink-table {
  width: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.pink-table>.list {
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.pink-table>.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 50px;
  gap: 5px;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.green-table {
  width: 50%;
  border: 5px solid green;
  background: lightgreen;
    position: relative;
}

.green-table>.list {
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.green-table>.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 50px;
  gap: 5px;
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.middle-div {
  background: gray;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  Logo, Navigation, Top Bar etc.
</nav>
<div class="tables">
  <div class="pink-table">
    <div class="list">
      Content area 1<br /><br /> Content area 1
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Area 1.1</button>
      <button>Area 1.2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-div">S<br />P<br />L<br />I<br />T<br />T<br />E<br />R</div>
  <div class="green-table">
    <div class="list">
      Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area
      2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2<br /><br />Content area 2
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Area 1.1</button>
      <button>Area 1.2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It looks really much organized, but the solution does not match all requirements for me: The button bars should be fixed at the bottom of the whole page, also if the content is smaller or higher than the available space or if the user resizes the browser window.

Comment: @teck0r I've seen all your comments to other answers, and my thought about this is that maybe you should set a defined height and width to occupy all the screen, from the top to the bottom, and it would make it have it's position "fixed" on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Do you mean to set a fix (absolute) height to the parent wrapper div container? In that case the reduce of the window size would lead to a non responsive behavior (scrollbar will be visible then). Maybe thats the only way to solve this... I am currently about to try some Javascript, but I don't like it either 

Comment: hey @teck0r, check my updated answer! I hope that was what you wanted :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works for me - Both of the top answers (you and Kameron) solves my problem very well - but yours is a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

In order for an `absolutely` positioned child to be relative to its parent, the parent must be `position: relative;`. See changes below.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      font-size: 30px
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    Logo, Navigation, Top Bar etc.
  </nav>

  <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;background:silver;position:absolute; left: 200px; right: 0; top: 2em; bottom: 0;">

    <div style="flex-basis:30%;order:0;border:5px solid red; position: relative; overflow: scroll;">
      <div style="background:pink; height: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
        Content area 1<br/><br/> Content area 1
      </div>

      <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px; right: 0; left: 0; text-align: end; background:pink; border-top: solid 1px black;">
        <div style="margin:10px 0;">
          <button>Area 1.1</button>
          <button>Area 1.2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="flex-basis:auto;flex-grow:1;flex-shrink:1;order:2;border:5px solid green; position: relative; overflow: scroll;">

      <div style="background:lightgreen; overflow: scroll; height: 100%;">
        Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2<br/><br/>Content area 2
      </div>

      <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px; right: 0; left: 0; text-align: end; background:lightgreen; border-top: solid 1px black;">
        <div style="margin:10px 0;">
          <button>Area 2.1</button>
          <button>Area 2.2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="flex-basis:auto;order:1;;background:gray; overflow: scroll;">S<br/>P<br/>L<br/>I<br/>T<br/>T<br/>E<br/>R</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and the tip with the `relative` keyword. The solution matches nearly all of the requirements for me. The only problem here: When I reduce the size of the browser window and scroll the "Content area 2", the buttons bar is in the middle of the area. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: @teck0r Yes, remove the `padding-bottom: 60px` and replace it with `height: 100%;` on both the `content area` parent divs. See edits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edited answer - this also works for me very well. So if I could I would also accept your answer, but I its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

this is for the left side but i think you want to make your position `sticky` but is maybe more efficient to change a lot of the code as someone else said...

```
 <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; background:pink; overflow: hidden; width: 30%;">
    <div style="margin:10px 0; position: relative; right: -223px;">
        <button>Area 1.1</button>
        <button>Area 1.2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately in a CSS-only solution I cannot work with "absolute" widths, because there is a draggable splitter between both areas. Maybe some javascript can help here? 